# Delete value by field type

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I have data in my bucket with different type, and I want to override or delete float data corresponding.

```
> SHOW FIELD KEYS
...
9   myindex   float
10  myindex   integer
...
```

I try to convert with flux, but I have an error

```
datatoconvert = from(bucket: "mybucket")
      |> range(start: -1y)
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "mymeasurement")
      |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "myindex")
      |> toInt()
 datatoconvert
      |> filter(fn: (r) => exists r._value)
      |> to(bucket: "mybucket")
```

error:

```
runtime error @12:8-12:29: to: partial write: field type conflict: input field "myindex" on measurement "mymeasurement" is type integer, already exists as type float dropped=3137
```

Answer (score 0):

InfluxDB stores data in the shard level. **Because of the the sharding strategy, two different field values could be inserted into the database.**

> Field value types cannot differ within a shard, but they can differ across shards.

> If field value types differ across shards, InfluxDB first performs any applicable cast operations and then returns all values with the type that occurs first in the following list: float, integer, string, Boolean.

> If your data have field value type discrepancies, use the syntax <field_key>:: to query the different data types.

See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/troubleshooting/frequently-asked-questions/#how-does-influxdb-handle-field-type-discrepancies-across-shards).

If you want to get rid of the undesired field value type, you could locate those records first and narrow their timestamps and then delete those records with the timestamp filter.

Sample code could be:

```
    influx delete --bucket example-bucket \
     --start '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z' \
     --stop '1970-01-01T00:00:01Z' \
     --predicate '_measurement="mymeasurement"
```

See delete statements [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/write-data/delete-data/#delete-data-using-the-influx-cli).